# replace the null value in result table to "0" in sql pivot table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null, pivot

I have this below query which will generate pivot table , but in the result i need to replace null value with "0"(zero) , kindly help me how to do the same:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    [Date],
    Department,
    Count(Action_Status) as Status
  FROM Semicon_NPD
  where Action_Status = 'Pending'
   group by Department,[Date]
) StatusCount
PIVOT (
  SUM([Status])
  FOR [Department]
  IN (
    [Milling],
    [Turning],
    [EDM]
  )
)
 AS PivotTable
```

result table:
[image]

Comment: @TT Thank you so much ..now it solved can you post the same as answer so that i can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `SELECT *` at the top. Change that to select the specific columns in the result set, and use [`ISNULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql) or [`COALESCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) to return 0 instead of NULL. Like so:

```
SELECT Date,Milling=ISNULL(Milling,0),Turning=ISNULL(Turning,0),EDM=ISNULL(EDM,0) 
FROM (
  SELECT
    [Date],
    Department,
    Count(Action_Status) as Status
  FROM Semicon_NPD
  where Action_Status = 'Pending'
   group by Department,[Date]
) StatusCount
PIVOT (
  SUM([Status])
  FOR [Department]
  IN (
    [Milling],
    [Turning],
    [EDM]
  )
)  AS PivotTable
```